# How to split audio, mix them and create another channel in kurento?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, kurento, video-conferencing

I am implementing a video conference app with a large number of people, and there was trouble with the internet to watch them all at the same time. I decided to create one independent audio channel, that will be listened always. Few videos should be shown, but at the same time I need to listen for all.

How to make this technique work?

I tried too many kurento examples. But about creating another channel no success. (

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You can try kurento `Composite`. It merges all streams (audio/video) connected though `HubPort` and sends merged stream out. But `Composite` causes High CPU usage on Kurento Media Server.

Follow this thread

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kurento/kXZ3CGo5WOA/q6ArbZ4HiasJ

Upvote if you found it useful.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with composite but do we have a technique to merge and split into two streams like video is not splited but audio is merged into one stream?

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement completely. Can you please clarify? As far as I understood, you want two streams that one with both audio and video merged and other with audio only. You can do that by creating separate endpoints and connect the media based on requirement(Audio+Video or Audio only). Just that for each one you need to separate endpoints.

Comment: My requirement is to get one common merged audio stream from all streams. And separated video streams. It is shown on this diagram https://pasteboard.co/JbP51i4.png

Comment: If you build using Composite, your Architecture would look something like this https://pasteboard.co/JbR8ztD.png . You can specity `MediaType` while `connecting` to endpoints like `source.connect(sink,MediaType.AUDIO)` . So, You'll be able to achieve your requirement as mentioned in the diagram. `Output 1 & 2` will receive only video stream and `Audio` output mentioned in the diagram will receive merged audio stream.